# iPhone broken falling from car

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I left my phone on the roof of my car today and drove off and the result was that I reversed over it and smashed the screen. I am insured so that is OK. The only problem I have is I haven't backed it up for 14 weeks as was running low on iCloud storage. I've taken all photos off so that's not the problem, but just need my calendar as I run my hairdressing business off it, and I cannot see all my appointments. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this on my PC?

Comment: You can access the iCloud calendar on MS Office - Outlook Calendar - [though it's been a while since I tried setting one up] so long as you also have the iCloud Control Panel & are signed in

Comment: Go to [the iCloud website](https://icloud.com), sign in with the Apple ID you used on your iPhone, and click on Calendar.

Comment: Is the Calendar only local to the iPhone, or did you synch it to iCloud? If you did, you can go to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com) and you should be able view the calendar there. YMMV

Answer (score 2):

iTunes on your PC can make a backup of your device quite easily - especially if you have the two devices paired before the fall.

If you haven't paired it, you'll need to have at least the digitizer working to tap to trust the computer once.

Once that's done (and iTunes will prompt you), you can use the PC to back up the entire phone and/or choose to synchronize the calendar data with the PC.

Best of luck and you probably could call AppleCare for free to arrange a repair and get help backing it up before he repair starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look at your calendar events through iCloud at icloud.com

Once you login with your Apple ID click on Calendar and check to make sure all of your events are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in your idevice and open itunes. There should be the device name up at the top bar of the screen. Click that and after that you should see your devices specs. Click the backup now button and continue. this will back up all of your apps, settings, calendar, so you can transfer it to another idevice.